# Tricentis Tosca: Illegal Workspace ID detected

Tags: testing, automated-tests, tosca

Getting the above error when trying to check items out in a Tosca workspace.

We had an error with our tws file previously and had to attempt to recreate this. I believe the way to fix this error would be to figure out what the correct workspace ID was. Any help on finding where this might be stored, or any other ideas on fixing the issue would be appreciated